# Django user permission by branch

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

If there is user belong to `branch_1` and `branch_2` but with different role/group in `branch_1` he is HR manager but in `branch_2` he is HR lets say with no edit permission or receives employee emails.

I don't think its correct to create group or permissions for `branch_1` and group for second one, and so on for every new relation between an user and a branch.
branch a group should be abstract from that.

What is the best approach to manage user permission per branch?

Comment: Explain what a branch is.

Comment: @SirajAlam a branch of company